# do not understand how array destructuring works here

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement a very simple cyclic sort in JS, and I am having issues with the swapping functionality of the algorithm.

```
const sort = (nums) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        while (nums[i] != i) {
            [nums[i], nums[nums[i]]] = [nums[nums[i]],nums[i]];
        }
    }
    return nums;
};
```

Here is my input:

`sort([1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6, 0])`

On the first iteration of the for and while loops, I get the following error:

```
            [nums[i], nums[nums[i]]] = [nums[nums[i]],nums[i]];
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '4')
```

In my node console, I tried a similar method, just without the dynamic index, and it worked.

```
> const arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
> [arr[0], arr[arr[2]]] = [arr[arr[2]], arr[0]]
[ 4, 1 ]
> arr
[ 4, 2, 3, 1, 5 ]
```

Looking at the ECMA script specification, at the `IteratorDestructuringAssignmentEvaluation`, I cannot figure out how JS is doing this destructuring, and why my method isn't working.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why taking a value instead of an index?

Comment: @NinaScholz what do you mean? I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: So if I'm on the right track here, perhaps this link would help. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/array-destructuring-in-es6-30e398f21d10/ . And towards the top of this page it says `You cannot use Numbers for destructuring. Numbers will throw an error because numbers cannot be variable names.`

Comment: Did you debug with a debugger? Evidently the `while` loop gets into an infinite loop in the first iteration of the outer `for`: it is setting `nums[1]` to 4 and then to 1 again, and to 4 again. This will never become 0.

Comment: @bob.mazzo im confused then, because that is exactly what i did in the nodejs console example that I posted

Comment: this is not a Cycle sort algorithm : array elements can't be used as array index values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs in your destructuring assignment:

```
[nums[i], nums[nums[i]]] =  ...
```

The order of assignment is that first `nums[i]` is assigned, and then the next array index is assigned. But there is the problem that next index (which is `nums[i]`) was just *updated*! So that second assignment is going to the wrong index.

You can solve this with a temporary variable:

```
let j = nums[i];
[nums[i], nums[j]] = [nums[j],nums[i]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use nums[temp]. This is because the assignment is done simultaneously, and the value of nums[temp] is updated before the swap completes.

```js
const sort = (nums) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        while (nums[i] !== i) {
            // Use a variable, otherwise it will not work
            const temp = nums[i];
            [nums[i], nums[temp]] = [nums[temp], temp];
        }
    }
    return nums;
};


// Example usage:
const sortedArray = sort([1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 0]);
console.log(sortedArray);
```